# Log4net - how to find out appender and it's properties at runtime?

Tags: .net, log4net

When debugging logging configuration, how do I see what appenders the logger is using and view specific appender's properties? I'm having trouble finding this info by looking at ILog logger in watch window.

[image]

Comment: I have to ask the obvious: Why do you need to check this at runtime?

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that you have no configured appenders.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni  When trouble shooting I would like to do a sanity check. Find out if the appenders and their values actually loaded.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov   LogManager.GetLoggerRepository().GetAppenders();  gives me the appender

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Perhaps this listing will give you what you need.

```
LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders();
```

Else, this may be of use to you also.

```
LogManager.GetLogger(yourLogger.GetType()).Logger.Repository.GetAppenders();
```